# How to apply different functions to different columns after groupby like sum and .apply(list)? (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe where I want to group rows based on a column. Some of the columns in the rows I want to sum up and the others I want to aggregate as a list.

```
#creating sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,4), columns=list('abcd'))
df['id'] = [1,2,1,4]
df['group'] = [[0,1,2,3] , [0,2,3,4], [1,1,1,1], 1]
df

Out[5]: 
          a         b         c         d  id         group
0  0.850058  0.160497  0.742296  0.354296   1  [0, 1, 2, 3]
1  0.598759  0.399200  0.799157  0.908174   2  [0, 2, 3, 4]
2  0.160764  0.671702  0.414800  0.429992   1  [1, 1, 1, 1]
3  0.011089  0.581518  0.718829  0.610140   4             1
```

Here I want to combine row 0 and row 2 as they have the same id. When doing this, I want to sum up the values in columns `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` but for column `group`, I want the lists to be appended. How can I do this?

My expected output is:

```
          a         b         c         d  id         group
0  1.155671 1.670582   0.392744  0.681494   1  [0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]
1  0.598759  0.399200  0.799157  0.908174   2  [0, 2, 3, 4]
2  0.011089  0.581518  0.718829  0.610140   4             1
```

(When I use only the `sum` or `df.groupby(['id'])['group'].apply(list)`, the other columns are dropped. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `groupby.aggregate`

```
df.groupby('id').agg({k: sum for k in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'group']})
```

A one-liner alternative would be using `numeric_only` flag. But be careful with the columns you are feeding in.

```
df.groupby('id').sum(numeric_only=False)
```

Output

```
           a         b         c         d                     group
id
1   1.488778  0.802794  0.949768  0.952676  [0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]
2   0.488390  0.512301  0.064922  0.233875              [0, 2, 3, 4]
4   0.649945  0.267125  0.229313  0.156696                         1
```

Comment: can use `"sum"` for the list column too, but that's an anti-pattern perhaps...

Comment: Good idea. Thanks @MustafaAydın

Comment: You could also grab the columns dynamically excluding `id` `df.columns.difference(['id'])`

Comment: I know that @HenryEcker. I leave it to the OP to decide based on his/her data.

Answer (score 2):

#### First Solution:

We can arrive at the task in 2 steps, the 1st step using `GroupBy.sum` to get the grouped sum of the first 4 columns.  The 2nd step acting on the column `group` only and concat the lists also by `GroupBy.sum`

```
df.groupby('id').sum().join(df.groupby('id')['group'].sum()).reset_index()
```

**Input**  **(Different values owing to the different random numbers generated)**

```
          a         b         c         d  id         group
0  0.758148  0.781987  0.310849  0.600912   1  [0, 1, 2, 3]
1  0.694848  0.755622  0.947359  0.708422   2  [0, 2, 3, 4]
2  0.515446  0.454484  0.169883  0.697287   1  [1, 1, 1, 1]
3  0.361939  0.325718  0.143510  0.077142   4             1
```

**Output**:

```
   id         a         b         c         d                     group
0   1  1.273594  1.236471  0.480732  1.298199  [0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]
1   2  0.694848  0.755622  0.947359  0.708422              [0, 2, 3, 4]
2   4  0.361939  0.325718  0.143510  0.077142                         1
```

#### Second Solution

We can also use [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) with ***named aggegation***, as follows:

```
df.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg(a=('a', 'sum'), b=('b', 'sum'), c=('c', 'sum'), d=('d', 'sum'), group=('group', 'sum'))
```

Result:

```
   id         a         b         c         d                     group
0   1  1.273594  1.236471  0.480732  1.298199  [0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]
1   2  0.694848  0.755622  0.947359  0.708422              [0, 2, 3, 4]
2   4  0.361939  0.325718  0.143510  0.077142                         1
```

Comment: The second solution is the same as my answer. You could keep it. But, it's always better to avoid duplicates :) @SeaBean

Comment: @Vishnudev  My second solution only partially similar but the part for `group` is different.  I also used `sum` for `group`.  Moreover, I used `named aggregation` for the aggregation.

Comment: @Vishnudev Oh, not aware you also changed the code for `group` from `explode().tolist()` to use `sum` as well.  Now more similar now.  Anyway, using `.sum()` for concatenate the lists had been used early in my first solution, right at the beginning.

Comment: No problem @SeaBean. Let it be there. Maybe the OP want's to rename the columns after aggregate.

Comment: @Vishnudev  That's fine.  No problem!

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
pd.merge(df.groupby('id', as_index = False).sum(), df.groupby('id')['group'].apply(sum).reset_index(), on = 'id')
    id  a           b           c           d           group
0   1   1.241602    0.839409    0.779673    0.639509    [0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]
1   2   0.967984    0.838906    0.313017    0.498611    [0, 2, 3, 4]
2   4   0.042871    0.367209    0.676656    0.178939    1
```